# On page load show specific table rows

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on this [website](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/)  and as you can see i have a table animated via JS and CSS.

What i need, if is possible, is to display specific rows on page load.

What i need is to display first the rows in the "Zimmer" column with the  `<td>2.5</td>` rows, then the rows `<td>3.5</td>` and at the end `<td>4.5</td>`

Is this possible?

If this can help i also have some filters buttons in JS at the top of the table that helps the user to filter the table informations.

Comment: What is "Zimmer"? Is that a value in the first cell in a certain column?

Comment: Bro one specific things in  a single question be simple precise and direct of what you require

Comment: You mean, you want to highlight just the one "attribute" of the row? Just add a custom css style to that specific <td>.

Comment: Yes this is possible.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload check this documentation out